# To allow for *word request* to regional regulations - to be uniquely aligned

Tags: word-request, synonyms

I'm using the following sentence in a set of bullet points outlining the perks of a certain product:

> Allows for parameters to be specified per country to allow for **them** [the parameters] **to be uniquely aligned** to regional regulations

My original plan was to use the following sentence:

> Allows for parameters to be specified per country to allow for ***allination*** regional regulations

I'm aware this obviously isn't a word and I was never *really* going to use it (hence changed the sentence to the one above). However, it got me wondering, is there another word I could have used?

Comment: To Glorfindel's answer I would add that it makes for uncomfortable reading when you repeat a key verb as in **allows....to allow for**.

Comment: @Ronald, you're absolutely right, it's a bit of a WIP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd slightly shorten the sentence and use *to comply with*:

> Allows for parameters to be specified per country to comply with regional regulations

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comply) defines it as

> 1 : to conform, submit, or adapt (as to a regulation or to another's wishes) as required or requested
>   // *comply* with federal law
>   // the devices *comply* with industry standards

Comment: Since I work in compliance, I really should have been able to think of this word...doy!

Answer (score 0):

I would shorten the sentence and not worry about that second verb at all:

> Allows for parameters to be specified per country **so they can be** uniquely aligned to regional regulations.

---

Since the word *allow* is used, it makes it sound as if the alignment with regional regulations is *possible*, but not necessarily a given, which is why I used *so they **can** be*.

But if it is a given, and if *unique alignment* is extraneous, the following could be used:

> Allows for parameters to be specified per country **so they follow** regional regulations.

---

Both versions of the sentence are predicated on an assumption that *they* [the parameters] should keep being mentioned.